# jQuery.post not working when using data type json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have been trying to utilize json in this jQuery.post because I need to return two values from my executed php.  The code was working when I was not implementing json.  I need to see if a promo code entered is valid for a particular broker.  The two variables I need back are the instant message whether or not it's valid (this is displayed to the user) and I need to update a hidden field that will be used later while updating the database.

The jQuery.post does not seem to be firing at all, but the code directly above it (the ajax-loader.gif) is working.

I did re-write the whole thing at one point using jQuery.ajax, and had issues there too.  Granted, I have probably been looking at this too long and have tried to re-write too many times, but any help is greatly appreciated!!

Here's the jQuery.post

```
<!-- Below Script is for Checking Promo Code Against Database-->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#promocode").keyup(function (e) {

    //removes spaces from PromoCode
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

    var promocode = jQuery(this).val();
    var brokerdealerid = document.getElementById("BrokerDealerId").value;

    if(promocode.length > 0 ){
        jQuery("#promo-result").html('<img src="../imgs/ajax-loader.gif" />');

        jQuery.post(
                '../check_promocode.php', 
                {promocode:promocode, brokerdealerid:brokerdealerid}, 
                function(data) {
                $("#promo-result").html(data.promoresult);
                $("#promo-result-valid").html(data.promovalid);
                },
                "json");
    }
}); 
});
</script>
<!-- End Script is for Checking Promo Code Against Database-->
```

Here's relevant code from check_promocode.php:

```
    //sanitize incoming parameters
if (isset($_POST['brokerdealerid'])) $brokerdealerid = sanitizeMySQL($_POST['brokerdealerid']);
$promocode = sanitizeMySQL($promocode);

//check promocode in db
$results = mysql_query("SELECT PromotionCodeIdentifier FROM PromotionCode WHERE PromotionCodeIdentifier='$promocode' AND BrokerDealerId='$brokerdealerid' AND PromotionCodStrtDte <= CURDATE() AND PromotionCodExpDte >= CURDATE()");
//return total count
$PromoCode_exist = mysql_num_rows($results); //total records

//if value is more than 0, promocode is valid
    if($PromoCode_exist) 
    {

        echo json_encode(array("promoresult"=>"Promotion Code Valid", "promovalid"=>"Y"));
        exit();

    }else{

        echo json_encode(array("promoresult"=>"Invalid Promotion Code", "promovalid"=>"N"));
        exit();
    }
```

As per request, here is what logs in the browser.  The ajax-loader just sits there displaying indefinitely as I enter in a promocode and a return message is never returned.  I don't really see any hard errors.

```
[00:30:41.985] GET http://localhost:8888/imgs/ajax-loader.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
[00:30:42.999] POST http://localhost:8888/check_promocode.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
[00:30:43.671] POST http://localhost:8888/check_promocode.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
[00:30:43.976] POST http://localhost:8888/check_promocode.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
[00:30:44.178] POST http://localhost:8888/check_promocode.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
```

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: use the firebug to check the request and response, and update it in your question.

Comment: Ugghh.. please don't kill me - like I said - I've been looking at this way too long... I just found some leftover debugging code in my php that was holding this up... The code actually works..   Also - thank you for the reference to checking the request and response - I never used that feature - really great advice.  Thanks to both of you!!

Comment: what does console.log(data); give you?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found some offending code...lol

```
$promocode = sanitizeMySQL($promocode);
```

Should be...

```
$promocode = sanitizeMySQL($_POST['promocode']);
```

Mybae that'll fix it...:)  Although I dont see how it will....because you were echoing an error if a row wasn't found, so you should've at the least received that error on the JSON/Jquery side.....so theres more to it.